# Could anyone explain this complex answer in simple words?

Tags: java, interface

I know there are loads of answers regarding Interfaces already present here but I am not asking any question regarding Interface. I am simply trying to understand the below mentioned answer.

I know what are Abstract classes and Interfaces, what's the difference & where to use them and how.But while looking at few interview questions I came across this one & which was answered in this way:

"The interface makes it possible for a method in one class to invoke methods on objects of other classes, without the requirement to know the true class of those objects, provided that those objects are all instantiated from classes that implement one or more specified interfaces. In other words, objects of classes that implement specified interfaces can be passed into methods of other objects as the generic type Object, and the methods of the other objects can invoke methods on the incoming objects by first casting them as the interface type."

Now can anyone explain in more simple words what the above answer means?

Comment: Better would be for you to tell us: Just what don't you understand about the explanation? The onus of effort in clarifying and specifying your question should be on you.

Comment: "You can call interface methods on any type as long as they implement that interface. You can pass an object of any type as an instance of an interface if the object implements that interface." If you know the difference between an abstract class and an interface, and know when to use each, the answer is a verbose reformulation of what you already think you know.

Comment: Frankly speaking "Nothing", it's just too confusing to get hold of it.

Comment: @user2861287 No, it means exactly what it says. Although the second part isn't really "in other words," and it could lead to what I'd consider a bad practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example.

If you have the following animal interface:

```
interface IAnimal {
   public void eat();
}
```

Which is implemented by the following classes:

```
class Tiger implements IAnimal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("Tiger eats antelope");
    }
}

class HouseCat implements IAnimal {
    public void eat() {
        System.out.println("House Cat eats canned food");
    }
}
```

Then you can do things like this:

```
public void whatDoesItEat(IAnimal animal) {
    animal.eat();
}

Tiger tiger = new Tiger();
HouseCat houseCat = new HouseCat();

whatDoesItEat(tiger);
whatDoesItEat(houseCat);
```

In `whatDoesItEat` you don't need to worry about what type of animal you are being passed.  You just care that each one implements the `IAnimal` interface, so that you can call the `eat()` method.

Comment: You know after looking at this I am feeling really silly for asking the question,anyways thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

> The interface makes it possible for a method in one class to invoke methods on objects of other classes, without the requirement to know the true class of those objects, provided that those objects are all instantiated from classes that implement one or more specified interfaces.

If a class implements an interface, anything can call interface methods on that class, without caring what the actual class is. E.g., you can pass objects around as an 
"instance" of one of its interfaces.

```
interface Fooable { void foo(); }
public class Bar implements Fooable { void foo() { System.out.println("Bar foo"); } }
public class Baz implements Fooable { void foo() { System.out.println("Baz foo"); } }
public class Plugh { void fooey(Fooable fooable) { fooable.foo(); } }
```

`Plugh` doesn't care anything about what the underlying type of its `Fooable` is. It only knows that it's a `Fooable`. It doesn't care that it could be a `Bar` or a `Baz`.

> In other words, objects of classes that implement specified interfaces can be passed into methods of other objects as the generic type Object, and the methods of the other objects can invoke methods on the incoming objects by first casting them as the interface type.

You *could* do this:

```
void fooey(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Fooable) {
        ((Fooable) o).foo();
    }
}
```

In general, you wouldn't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, it means that if you have a method that takes an interface as an argument :

```
void someFunction(SomeInterface si)
```

then you can call it with any class that implements that interface.